# How to make a movie of a subplot, in which each subplot is a frame?

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-figure, subplot

I have to do exactly what my title says. I have a figure with a subplot, for example 3-by-5. I want to take all different graph inside the subplot and make each one of them a frame (in this case, 15 different frames). I have tried different solution but nothing worked. For example I tried:

```
writerObj = VideoWriter('try.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate = 1;
open(writerObj);
h= figure(1);

for x=1:15
    hh=subplot(3,5, x);
    frame=getframe(hh);
    writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
end
close(writerObj);
```

Or I tried

```
writerObj = VideoWriter('try.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate = 1;
open(writerObj);
h= figure(1);
fig=gcf;
axesHandles = get(gcf,'children');
for x=1:15
    hh=subplot(3,5, x);
    frame=getframe(axesHandles(x));
    writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
end
close(writerObj);
```

Comment: I try to do a little tweak in the code, saving each frame in a vector called frame and then play everything in a movie(frame). This kind of work, but not perfectly, and give me a good hint why my previous way didn't work. It seems that the different subplot are  different in size. I don't understand why is that. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Please tell us *why* these didn't work? What were the problems or errors? IS it because your frames/axes aren't the same size?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that. Yes, this is the problem reported to matlab. But the axis should be of the same size. I am now thinking that the problem could be that the value i give to the axes is a double, so maybe matlab can modify in an odd way the axes for each subplot so that it's not always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue has to do with the `'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode'` property of your axes being set to `'auto'` when they're first created. You'll need to specify your axis limits with [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) or use of the other options. If it's suitable for your data, try specifying `axis equal` for each axis. Or maybe `axis square`.